# How to remove all occurrences in array and shift leftovers left?

Tags: c#

We have  two arrays of integers `a1` and `a2` as parameters and we should remove all occurrences of `a2` values from `a1`. Element is "removed" by shifting all subsequent elements one index to the left to cover it up, placing a 0 into the last index. The original relative ordering of `a1` elements should be retained.

i'm having problem with shifting it's element.

Example:

```
int[] a1 = { 42, 3, 9, 42, 42, 0, 42, 9, 42, 42, 17, 8, 2222, 4, 9, 0, 1};

int[] a2 = { 42, 2222, 9};
```

the final result should be like this:

```
{3, 0, 17, 8, 4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

so here is my code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
{
    foreach(var element in a2)
    {
        if (element == a1[i])
        {
            for(int j = i; j < a1.Length-1; j++)
            {
                a1[j] = a1[j+1];
            }
            a1[a1.Length - 1] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your code seems to work, or maybe I have missed something

Comment: i'm having problem with shifting it's element.

Comment: my code creates {3,42,0,...}
how can i fix it?

Comment: @mobikaoxox this is a school assignment, isn't it?

Comment: nope,it's a practice from this site
https://www.codestepbystep.com/problem/view/csharp/arrays/Banish

Comment: How about leveraging `Array.Copy` for the shifting? It can not only be used to copy array content from one array to another, it can also be used to copy a continuous region/block of an array within the same array (shifting can be understood as such a copy operation). However, note that `Array.Copy` only works with arrays, and not with other 'index-addressable' collections like `List<T>`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `i--;` when your item matches. Because you're shifting your entire array. Also you need to use `break;` your inner `foreach` loop after `i--;`.

**Explanation**

**1)** With your arrays, for `i = 0` and first element in `foreach(var element in a2)` both will be `42`. So first your array will be shifted one index. Now if you are not using `i--` then it will check for `i=1` which should be `3` but as we already shifted our array so `3` value is at index `0`. So this value will never getting checked for match.

**2)** And use of `break`, as your match already found and array is shifted there is no requirement for check further.

Your code should be like below.

```
for(int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
{       
    foreach(var element in a2)
    {
        if (element == a1[i])
        {
            for(int j = i; j < a1.Length-1; j++)
            {
                a1[j] = a1[j+1];
            }
            a1[a1.Length - 1] = 0;
            i--;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If You can use Linq then try as below, First get filters elements first. Then add `0` for rest indexes.

```
int[] a1= { 42,3,9,42,42,0,42,9,42,42,17,8,2222,4,9,0,1};
int[] a2= { 42,2222,9};
var a3 = a1.Where(x => !a2.Contains(x)).ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++) {
    if (i < a3.Length)
        a1[i] = a3[i];
    else
        a1[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me why you use break and i--?

Comment: @mobikaoxox Updated my answer with explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without creating any extra arrays like so:

```
static void Main()
{
    int[] a1 = { 42, 3, 9, 42, 42, 0, 42, 9, 42, 42, 17, 8, 2222, 4, 9, 0, 1 };
    int[] a2 = { 42, 2222, 9 };

    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; ++i)
        if (Array.IndexOf(a2, a1[i]) < 0) // Don't remove this value.
            a1[j++] = a1[i];

    Array.Clear(a1, j, a1.Length-j);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", a1));
}
```

We make two passes: Firstly to remove all the elements of `a1` that are contained in `a2` (via the explicit loop) and then to overwrite all the "removed" values with `0` (via `Array.Clear()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a different approach by first filtering and then adding the needed zeros:

```
int[] a1 = { 42, 3, 9, 42, 42, 0, 42, 9, 42, 42, 17, 8, 2222, 4, 9, 0, 1 };
int[] a2 = { 42, 2222, 9 };

var zeros = Enumerable.Repeat(0, int.MaxValue);
var valids = a1.Where(v => !a2.Contains(v));
var result = valids.Concat(zeros).Take(a1.Length);

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", result));
```

Comment: I think this is a school assignment for loop/array learning. Using Linq isn't really a good approach to learn.

Comment: @Cid, No clear constraint in the question. I see clear understandable code. I found clear linq really valuable in the learning process as it provide a clear algo and path to a solution that will be hard to express otherwise. Using LinQ trend to push people to express more clearly with shorter sentence. Avoiding the "loop on this" where you forget what you want to do focussing to mutch on how.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach, using `Array.Copy`for shifting:

```
public static void Main()
{               
    int[] a1 = { 42, 3, 9, 42, 42, 0, 42, 9, 42, 42, 17, 8, 2222, 4, 9, 0, 1 };
    int[] a2 = { 42, 2222, 9 };

    for(int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
    {
        if(a2.Contains(a1[i]))
        {
            //notice i-- here because iterating array shifted to left
            ShiftToLeft(a1, i--+1);         
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", a1));
}

private static void ShiftToLeft(int[] array, int fromIndex)
{
    Array.Copy(array, fromIndex, array, fromIndex-1, array.Length - fromIndex);
    array[array.Length-1] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
            int[] a1 = { 42, 3, 9, 42, 42, 0, 42, 9, 42, 42, 17, 8, 2222, 4, 9, 0, 1 };
            int[] a2 = { 42, 2222, 9 };

            var result = a1.Where(x => !a2.Contains(x)).Concat(new int[a1.Length]).Take(a1.Length);

            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", result));
```